# Hash position after refresh different

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was coding an anchor navigation on a single page design. But I have some problems with the position of the section on refreshing. When I click on an external page that has the same navigation structure, onlyn add before al anchor hash in the a tag `index.html`, for example `index.html#video`.

When I click on video it will go to that section, but after reload it has a different target value, then before.

What can be the problem and the solution for this?

My JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/E773g/43/

Comment: How are you reloading the page?

Comment: With the refresh button or ctrl+r (mac). @Doge

Comment: If the idea is that you click one of the links at the top, and you refresh the page, it's still scrolled down. Then that part works. I'm not sure what your question is. If you don't want it to scroll down then don't define the anchor.

Comment: When you are on an external page, like `single.html` and you click a link in the menu that links to a section on the homepage `index.html`, than it goes to that section. OK? When refreshing the page then, the browser will scroll to that part, but it stops too early, so you can see another section. @doge